# Display only subcategory product thumbnail woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having some problems displaying thumbnails for subcategory. Can anyone help me?

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ){
    $category_name = $term->name;
    $category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
    $image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'">';
}?>
```

I want to show only thumbnails of SUBCATEGORY , and the above code does not help that problem. Thks

Answer (score 0):

Please check following code and try it.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ){
    if( $term->parent != 0 ) {
        $category_name = $term->name;
        $category_thumbnail = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);
        echo '<img src="'.$image.'">';
    }
}
```

Check if the Parent id is not 0 or you can check like $term->parent > 0. Get the term meta of the term_id.

get_woocommerce_term_meta function may be deprecated and you can use get_term_meta to get term meta.

Comment: Glad that it works for you! Please mark the answer as accepted to let other guys gets help out from the answer.